# PayPal Subscription Button Error when selecting "Pay using your credit or debit card"

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

My client created a hosted Subscription button and gave me following code to apply in our website:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="X9Z9BHN867R2E">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

On Paypal's Checkout screen there are 2 options:
1) Already have PayPal account (2) Create PayPal account.

If I choose first option and enter a wrong username/password. Then I see a link: "Pay using your credit or debit card". When user clicks on this link, it just throws an error: "The link you have used to enter the PayPal system is invalid. Please review the link and try again."

What is the possible cause of this issue? Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug at PayPal end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly an error on PayPal's side. If you click on the hosted subscription button using a browser with no PayPal cookies, you will see a screen that says **"You need a PayPal account for this purchase."** and then two radio buttons:

> - I already have a PayPal account. (and then fields for entering your Email and Password)
> - I need to create a PayPal account (where available).

HOWEVER, if you click on a hosted subscription button using a browser *with* PayPal cookies (in other words, used by *someone* that has a PayPal account -- not necessarily your user, but anyone that has used that browser to logon to PayPal in the past), then the screen **does NOT** say you need a PayPal account for this purchase, instead it says:

> **Check out using PayPal** (followed by fields for entering your Email and Password).
>
> And below that (and it's a little hard to see at first), it says: **"No PayPal account? Pay using your credit or debit card"**

If you click on that, you will get the following error:

> The link you have used to enter the PayPal system is invalid. Please review the link and try again.

PayPal *requires* a PayPal account for subscription payments, but for reasons only PayPal knows, they have chosen to have a link on the form that suggests otherwise and only confuses poor users when they click on it (who were trying to give you money, I might add) and then vaguely they are told there was an error.

**Perhaps the only current work around -- until someone brings it to PayPal's attention -- would be to warn your users on your checkout page that a PayPal account is required for subscription payments.**

Answer (score 2):

this sounds like enhanced recurring payments.  Your client must verify the Paypal account using email and this should solve your problem.

AR